# What is DarwinBoolean type in Swift

Tags: swift

I have written `Boolean` instead of `Bool` in some Swift code and Xcode offered me to replace it with `DarwinBoolean`.

The question is, what exactly is `DarwinBoolean`?

What are the differences comparing to `Bool` and `ObjCBool` types.
What is it's purpose?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Short answer:

- `Bool` is the native Swift type for truth values.
- `DarwinBoolean` is the Swift mapping of the "historic" C type `Boolean`.
- `ObjCBool` is the Swift mapping of the Objective-C type `BOOL`.

You would use `Bool` in your Swift code unless one of the other types
is required for interoperability with existing Core Foundation or 
Objective-C functions.

---

**More about `DarwinBoolean`**: 
`DarwinBoolean` is defined in Swift as

```
/// The `Boolean` type declared in MacTypes.h and used throughout Core
/// Foundation.
///
/// The C type is a typedef for `unsigned char`.
public struct DarwinBoolean : BooleanType, BooleanLiteralConvertible {
    public init(_ value: Bool)
    /// The value of `self`, expressed as a `Bool`.
    public var boolValue: Bool { get }
    /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
    public init(booleanLiteral value: Bool)
}
```

and is the Swift mapping of the "historic" C type `Boolean` from 
[MacTypes.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacTypes.h):

```
/********************************************************************************

    Boolean types and values

        Boolean         Mac OS historic type, sizeof(Boolean)==1
        bool            Defined in stdbool.h, ISO C/C++ standard type
        false           Now defined in stdbool.h
        true            Now defined in stdbool.h

*********************************************************************************/
typedef unsigned char                   Boolean;
```

See also the Xcode 7 Release Notes:

> The type Boolean in MacTypes.h is imported as Bool in contexts that
>   allow bridging between Swift and Objective-C types.
>
> In cases where the representation is significant, Boolean is imported
>   as a distinct DarwinBoolean type, which is BooleanLiteralConvertible
>   and can be used in conditions (much like the ObjCBool type).
>   (19013551)

As an example, the functions

```
void myFunc1(Boolean b);
void myFunc2(Boolean *b);
```

are imported to Swift as

```
public func myFunc1(b: Bool)
public func myFunc2(b: UnsafeMutablePointer<DarwinBoolean>)
```

In `myFunc1` there is an automatic conversion between the native
Swift type `Bool` and the Mac Type `Boolean`. 
This is not possible in `myFunc2` because the *address* of a variable
is passed around, here `DarwinBoolean` is exactly the Mac Type `Boolean`.

In previous versions of Swift – if I remember correctly – this mapped
type was called `Boolean`, and has been renamed to `DarwinBoolean` later.

---

**More about `ObjCBool`**: 
`ObjCBool` is the Swift mapping of the Objective-C type `BOOL`,
this can be `signed char` or the C/C++ `bool` type, depending on the
architecture. For example, the `NSFileManager` method

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path
         isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory
```

is imported to Swift as

```
func fileExistsAtPath(_ path: String,
      isDirectory isDirectory: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool
```

Here the `BOOL` return value is converted to `Bool` automatically,
but the `(BOOL *)` is kept as `UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>`
because it is the *address* of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no real documentation of the DarwinBoolean except the part that was posted in the former answer.

But generally the Darwin package which can be imported seperatelly or accessed through the Foundation package is used when you want to use mathematical functions.

The value of the `DarwinBoolean` is the same as the normal bool, true or false.