# Representing NULL Function Pointers to C Functions in Swift

Tags: c, swift, function-pointers, iphone-privateapi

Consider the private-yet-sort-of-documented Cocoa C functions `_NSLogCStringFunction()` and `_NSSetLogCStringFunction()`.  `_NSLogCStringFunction()` returns a function pointer to the C function used by the Objective-C runtime behind-the-scenes for `NSLog()`, and `_NSSetLogCStringFunction()` allows developers to specify their own C function for logging.  More information on both of these functions can be found in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35881034/2415822) and [this WebObjects support article](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA45403?locale=en_US).

In C, I can pass in a NULL function pointer to `_NSSetLogCStringFunction()`:

```
extern void _NSSetLogCStringFunction(void(*)(const char*, unsigned, BOOL));

_NSSetLogCStringFunction(NULL); // valid
```

However, I'm running into some issues when I try to do this in pure Swift:

```
/// Represents the C function signature used under-the-hood by NSLog
typealias NSLogCStringFunc = (UnsafePointer<Int8>, UInt32, Bool) -> Void

/// Sets the C function used by NSLog
@_silgen_name("_NSSetLogCStringFunction")
func _NSSetLogCStringFunction(_: NSLogCStringFunc) -> Void

_NSSetLogCStringFunction(nil) // Error: nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'NSLogCStringFunc' (aka '(UnsafePointer<Int8>, UInt32, Bool) -> ()')
```

If I try bypass this compile-time warning with `unsafeBitCast`, my program just crashes with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` (as expected, since the signature is wrong):

```
let nullPtr: UnsafePointer<Void> = nil
let nullFuncPtr = unsafeBitCast(nullPtr, NSLogCStringFunc.self)
_NSSetLogCStringFunction(nullFuncPtr) // crash
```

How do I represent a `NULL` function pointer to `(void *)` or `(void(*)(const char *, unsigned, BOOL))`/`(UnsafePointer<Int8>, UInt32, Bool) -> Void` in Swift?

Comment: lol, instant downvote for whatever reason - there was not even time to read the entire question.

Comment: @luk2302 Guess I have a fan :)  That's a new record for me, -1 in 44 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Swift mapping of the (Objective-)C declaration

```
extern void _NSSetLogCStringFunction(void(*)(const char*, unsigned, BOOL));
```

is

```
public func _NSSetLogCStringFunction(_: (@convention(c) (UnsafePointer<Int8>, UInt32, ObjCBool) -> Void)!)
```

The easiest solution would be to put the Objective-C `extern`
declaration into an Objective-C header file and include that 
from the bridging header.

Alternatively, in pure Swift it should be

```
typealias NSLogCStringFunc = @convention(c) (UnsafePointer<Int8>, UInt32, ObjCBool) -> Void

@_silgen_name("_NSSetLogCStringFunction")
func _NSSetLogCStringFunction(_: NSLogCStringFunc!) -> Void
```

In either case, the function parameter is an implicitly unwrapped optional,
and you can call it with `nil`. Example:

```
func myLogger(message: UnsafePointer<Int8>, _ length: UInt32, _ withSysLogBanner: ObjCBool) -> Void {
    print(String(format:"myLogger: %s", message))
}

_NSSetLogCStringFunction(myLogger) // Set NSLog hook.
NSLog("foo")
_NSSetLogCStringFunction(nil) // Reset to default.
NSLog("bar")
```

Output:

```
myLogger: foo
2016-04-28 18:24:05.492 prog[29953:444704] bar
```

Comment: Ugh, really?  All I needed to do was change `Bool` to `ObjCBool`? -_-  There are too many Bool types in Swift.  Thanks Martin.

Comment: @JAL: And the `@convention(c)` and the implicitly unwrapped parameter.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `ObjCBool` is required.  Looks like I was just missing the `@convention(C)` and the implicitly unwrapped parameter.  Using `Bool` with the other two seems to work.  Are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: @JAL: That may be, but `ObjCBool` is what the "Generated Interface" shows for the Objective-C declaration, so that's what *I* would use.

Comment: Yes, I see the same thing.  But can't `ObjCBool` be used interchangeably with Swift's `Bool` type like `CBool`?  Or is this a special case since `CBool` is a typealias of `Bool`.

Comment: @JAL: I wrote a bit about the various bools here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33667761/1187415. `BOOL` is often mapped to `Bool`, but not always. I am not sure if that applies here for the function pointer. – But in my experience the "Generated Interface" shows the correct mapping.