# IBM MFP Logs disabling on ios simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I have disabled all the NSLogs/print from my ios/swift project. But MFP Sdk is still logging the response when i run the app on simulator. When i run the app on device then it works properly by not showing any logs. How can i disable on simulator also??

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680004/redirect-nslog-to-file-in-swift-not-working (redirect NSLog output) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916772/representing-null-function-pointers-to-c-functions-in-swift (intercept NSLog calls)

Comment: Can i know why exactly you want to disable logging in Simulator ?? MFP SDK is enabled with logging only when you run app on simulator architectures. As simulator is meant for app development and testing phases.

Comment: @VittalPai Lets say if someone has the .IPA/.APP and is able to run it on simulator. I want to disable the logging in this case also.

Comment: @mkamran Apple won't allow you to build IPA packaged with simulator slices. So, I don't think that you are able to install .IPA and run it on simulators.

Comment: @VittalPai Lets say i created a .app file for my application for someone who want to test it on a simulator. A file exported as .app will run on a simulator. But i don't want him to see any logs from the application.

Comment: @mkamran You can try out, if that's the case please open a PMR with IBM. Apple won't allow you to install/run .IPA in simulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable logs in MFP 7.x SDK's while running on simulator as it is meant for development and testing phases.

You can raise a request for enhancement of MFP product [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/).