# IBM Mobile First Platform Foundation printing logs on XCode console

Tags: swift, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to stop printing logs on XCode console. I am using IBM MobileFirst platform (IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation) framework  inside my ios app. Below are the problems i am facing,
1) I am able to see the request and response on console. (Want to stop printing it)
2) How can I stop IBM MobileFirst platform from printing logs on console? please help me out on the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBM MFP Logs disabling on ios simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494278/ibm-mfp-logs-disabling-on-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with [APAR PI79173](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI79173)

Now, the printing of request and response appears only within XCode console. This is because your application is itself running in Debug mode.

This information is no longer logged when running release mode on a real device, if security is your concern.

Comment: Security is big concern for me, I tried with release mode still logs getting print :(

Comment: This has been fixed in APAR :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI79173
What iFix level are you on?

Comment: Updated answer with iFix level that fixes the issue.

Comment: My version is 7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

By default, log capture is enabled. Log capture saves logs to the client, and can be enabled or disabled programmatically. Logs are sent to the server with an explicit send call, or with auto log.

To disable log capturing:

**In Swift**

```
OCLogger.setCapture(false);
```

Comment: Gaurab, not worked for me :( still logs are printing