# How to tracks all calls to NSLog(), Swift print() and other print-family functions in swift

Tags: ios, swift, macros, nslog

Here i want track all NSLog(), Swift print() and other print-family functions.

Means i want to track all log print on debugging window in xcode and save to local storage.

I have tried with macro and this is my code but not worked for me.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define NSLog(args...) ExtendNSLog(__FILE__,__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,args)
#else
#define NSLog(x...)
#endif

void _Log(NSString *prefix, const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, NSString *format,...);
```

Now i want everytime NSLog() print anything it will call this method and than i store it into one file simple.

If you want more details please ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41680004/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36916772/1187415

Comment: Check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026752/swift-extending-functionality-of-print-function

Answer (score 1):

Add this to any `.swift` file in your project. This function will be called everytime `print()` is called in your project.

```
public func print(_ items: Any...) {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(items)
        // append items to your file here
    #else
        Swift.print("Release")
    #endif
}
```

Comment: This is custom print fucntion i want to override NSLog() when ever we used NSLog() it will call my method in whole app not only in particular view.

Comment: @HardikVyas this will be called in whole app. declare this function globally. just copy paste it in your Project and put a breakpoint inside. You will find out.

Comment: can we do same for NSLog() ??

Comment: @HardikVyas no idea. Your question asked for Swift print(), so I answered for it.

Comment: @KeshuR.: The question asked for *“NSLog(), Swift print() and other print-family functions”*

Comment: @MartinR right. I had an answer for Swift print(), so I added as it might be helpful. If it is not, I may remove.

Comment: @MartinR Right I want every log which is print on debugging window.